# Search among artboards and symbols in sketch-app

Tags: sketch-app, shortcuts

I am using sketch ver. 51.1.

Is it a way to search among artboards and components in order to access them quickly? I want to search in whole project, not just in current page.

If it is possible with plugin, please introduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searches I found a plugin which is a good tool in order to search quickly in sketch: [Sketch Runner](https://sketchrunner.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Filter" box on the bottom left of the screen, under the Layer List.

[image: this little guy here filters for you]

If you switch to the **Symbols** inspector you'll see only symbols, and in the Pages you'll see, well, anything in the pages that match your filter.

From [the user manual](https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/the-interface/layer-list/):

> Slices could previously be filtered in this bar, but they can now be toggled from the **View** menu. Choose **Show Slices** to adjust their visibility in the **Canvas**.

Comment: Thank you Luciano, but it filter in current page. I want to search among **whole** symbols and artboards of my project, not only current page.

Comment: @KeivanSina oh you didn't specify that in the question, can you please edit it to include that information? But anyway I'm affraid what you're asking for is not possible, perhaps with a plugin.